# Does the packaging action builds the project?

Tags: spring, maven

When we launch the maven command `mvn package` , does this command builds the Spring project at the same time ? Or does it just create the packaging file ?

Comment: `package` is a part of the maven life cycle which means all phase will be run through and yes the result is that all things will be created (compiled etc.)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - **Yes**!

Long answer:

Maven has a set of lifecycles (from https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html):

1. validate
2. compile
3. test
4. package
5. verify
6. install
7. deploy

Executing any given lifecycle will first execute the previous lifecycles - so when running `mvn package` it will first execute `validate`, then `compile`, then `test`, and then finally `package`.

If you run `mvn package` (or even just `mvn compile`) and check your `target/classes` directory you'll find your compiled `.class` files.